# Why does XamlWriter adds a {} to some attributes?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, xamlwriter

I'm saving a resource dictionary to `Xaml` using `XamlWriter` and I noticed that for `string` properties with just `{p}`, the `XamlWriter` adds a `{}` before the text (resulting in `{}{p}`).

Why does that happen? Is there any way to prevent this?
Or at least to remove it safely when read back using a standard `XDocument.Parse()`?

Here's how I'm saving it:

```cs
public class Example 
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

var resource = new ResourceDictionary();
resource.Add("Example", new Example { Property = "{p}" });

var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = "\t",
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    CheckCharacters = true,
    CloseOutput = true,
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
};

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream, settings))
    XamlWriter.Save(resource, writer);
```

### Edit

The `{}` is a scape sequence that is added when the text contains an open and close brackets like `{...}`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/escape-sequence-markup-extension

Now, the only question remaining is how can I safely remove these scape sequences from my text. Can I simply do a replace or trim, or is there a method for that already?

Comment: It was not needed, the question was about the theory, but I already know why it's happening. I just wish to know if there's a simple and safe way to remove the scape sequences from the Xaml.

Comment: The curly brackets are uses for binding.  So removing the brackets the bindings will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces are added to escape braces in the values being serialized. You shouldn't really remove them.

> or is there a method for that already?

No, there isn't. *If* you want to modify the written text, you are on your own. Using `string.Replace` or similar would be sufficient. There is no better built-in way.